# Dynamically generate fields+1 for model form

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that is basically just a service report.  I want this model to contain multiple punches (clock in\clock out).  How do I go about doing that?  When I pull up the form, I want to be able to add punches obviously.

```
class ServiceReportModel(models.Model):
    report_number = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    site = models.ForeignKey(customers_models.SiteModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    request_number = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequestModel,
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       related_name='s_report_number'
                                       )
    reported_by = models.ForeignKey(main_models.MyUser, related_name='reports')
    reported_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(main_models.MyUser, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(customers_models.EquipmentModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    report_reason = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    actions_taken = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    recommendations = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('service-report', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s, %s' % (self.site.company, self.reported_date.strftime('%d %B %Y'), self.equipment.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['reported_date']
        verbose_name = 'Service Report'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Service Reports'
```

Comment: This is what model formsets are for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman based on your comment and some research, am I to understand it that you're suggesting I move the time-in\out into their own model and foreignkey them, then itterate through the formset that is specific to that service report ID?

I have to ask because I haven't used formsets yet, so I have no idea the use or implementation :)